# Search a value in all tables in a connection (Sql developer)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I found many such questions but the answers where all using Stored Procedures.
I want an answer that uses purely a query in Oracle Sql Developer.

I have a value 'CORE_AO0001031_70_EMail_1' but not sure in which table. The number of tables and the data inside them are very huge.

Doesn't matter if the query is huge and will take time to execute. Is there any such query?

The reason for my asking a query is, I don't have privilege to create a Stored Procedure and I won't be given that privilege. Please help me with a query.

Comment: But you can execute an anonymous block right? This need is for only one usage or for a frequent usage? If not a problem for you, just paste whatever sp you found into an anonymous block and run it.

Comment: Execute an anonymous block? I don't get you. I will use that query later, depending on the demands.

Comment: Atleast you have a schema name in which u need a search ?

Comment: just do this: `BEGIN /* PL/SQL CODE PARSING ALL TABLES */ END;`

Comment: @Freakyuser [Anonymous blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_packages.htm#i1006270).

Comment: I understand, @Freakyuser does not want tu use PL\SQL he need SQL query.

Comment: Also I don't know how to debug a PL/SQL table, so a query will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

With an SQL you can't, as the queries are going to be dynamic. You have to execute a PL/SQL atleast.
**Note:** This is a Costly operation!

You can still attempt a full download of all you tables as spooling, and make `PERL` search into all files. In that case, you need a lot of disk space, but less harm(Just better than the `Pl/SQL`) to the database

```
DECLARE
TYPE TY_TABLE_NAMES IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
L_TABLE_NAMES TY_TABLE_NAMES;

TYPE TY_COLUMN_NAMES IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
L_COLUMN_NAMES TY_COLUMN_NAMES;

v_SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR2(30) = 'SYSTEM'; --Your Schema Name

v_QUERY_STRING VARCHAR2(4000);

v_SEARCH_STRING VARCHAR2(4000) := 'CORE_AO0001031_70_EMail_1';

v_SEARCH_FLAG CHAR(1) := 'N';
BEGIN
SELECT ALL_TABLES 
BULK COLLECT INTO L_TABLE_NAMES
WHERE OWNER = v_SCHEMA_NAME;

FOR I In 1..L_TABLE_NAMES.COUNT LOOP
   SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
   BULK COLLECT INTO L_COLUMN_NAMES
   FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
   WHERE TBALE_NAME = L_TABLE_NAMES(I)
     AND OWNER = v_SCHEMA_NAME;

   FOR J In 1..L_COLUMN_NAMES.COUNT LOOP
       BEGIN
             v_QUERY_STRING := 'SELECT ''Y''  FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ''X'' FROM '||L_TABLE_NAMES(I)||' WHERE '||
                              ||L_COLUMN_NAMES(J)|| ' LIKE ''%'|| v_SEARCH_STRING||'%'')';
             EXCECUTE IMMEDIATE v_QUERY_STRING INTO v_SEARCH_FLAG;
       WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            v_SEARCH_FLAG := 'N';
       END;

       IF(v_SEARCH_FLAG = 'Y') THEN
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_SEARCH_STRING || ' found in column '||L_COLUMN_NAMES(I)|| ' of table '||L_TABLE_NAMES(I));
           BREAK;
       END IF;
   END LOOP;
   IF(v_SEARCH_FLAG = 'Y') THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Done Searching!');
       BREAK;
   END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: No indexes will be used, so much CPU used. All full table scans.! Also, time.

Comment: Is there a query to do this? The problem with the above PL/SQL for me is, I have to make minor changes to it but I don't know how to.

Comment: Unfortunately no, may be facebook me ;)